# R- How to use map() into map()

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I need access a tibble table that is in a `nest()` function inside of another `nest()` function.

```
x <- list( factory = c('a','b','c','d'), cost = c(21,30,44,100))
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x <-  x %>%
        melt('cost','factory')
colnames(x) <- c('cost','client','type')
x <- x %>%
  group_by(client)%>%
  nest()

for (m in 1:4) {
  if(m==1){
    x$scene <- m
    x2 <- x
  }else{
    x3 <- x
    x3$scene <- m
    x2 <- rbind(x2,x3)
  }
}
x2 <- x2 %>%
  group_by(scene) %>%
  nest()
```

What am I trying to do is applying a function inside of first vector, something like:

```
test <- function(df){
  df$data %>%
  mutate(increa = cost + 15)
}

x2$data%>%
  map(test)
```

`dput(x2)` result a:

> structure(list(scene = 1:4, data = list(structure(list(client =
>   structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>       "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(client =
>   structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>       "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(client =
>   structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>       "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(client =
>   structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
>       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), type = c("a", 
>       "b", "c", "d")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>       "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class =
>   c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

The expected result:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`factory`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[1]]$cost
[1]  21  30  44 100

[[1]]$increa
[1]  36  45  59 115


[[2]]
[[2]]$`factory`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]$cost
[1]  21  30  44 100

[[2]]$increa
[1]  36  45  59 115


[[3]]
[[3]]$`factory`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[3]]$cost
[1]  21  30  44 100

[[3]]$increa
[1]  36  45  59 115


[[4]]
[[4]]$`factory`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[4]]$cost
[1]  21  30  44 100

[[4]]$increa
[1]  36  45  59 115
```

Someone could help me to solve this issue?

## **ANSWER**

This is the result that I was looking for:

```
map(x2$data, function(df) map(df$data, function(df) df <- mutate(df,increa = cost + 15)))
```

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output here? And it seems you have an extra`}` in your example code.

Comment: A new column:  mutate(increa = cost + 15) @MrFlick

Comment: So you want to keep the column called "data" that contains tibbles each with one column also named "data" that will have three columns called "factory", "cost" and "increa"? This is a very weird structure. Are you sure you want the doubly nested data elements?

Comment: Yes @MrFlick, that's exactly what I need. The first nest () is just a way to create many scene, changing just a few parameters

Comment: I think you are looking for something like `x2 %>% mutate(data = map(data, test))`, but the problem is that your datasets in the data column don't have a data column themselves and thus the test function is not working--- If you remove the `$data` in your test function does it give you your desired output?

Comment: isn't working @kath

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with a structure using `dput` and then add an expected output? That might make it easier to help you.

Comment: it's done @kath

Comment: Oh that's really nested... this works but I'm not happy enoughg to post it as an answer.... let me know whether that the right direction: `my_data %>% 
  pull(data) %>% 
  map(function(df1) map(df1$data, function(df2) mutate(df2, increa = cost + 15)))`

Comment: @kath the code is working just in the first tibble, but the direction is correctly

Comment: I got with this code:
`map(x2$data, function(df) map(df$data, function(df) mutate(df, increa = cost + 15)))` @kath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output I think it is easier first to extract the level of information you want to have and then calculate the new column. If you on the other hand want to manipulate the data in this structure and preserve this, than a nested call of `map` and `mutate` is necessary-

```
library(tidyverse)
```

**First solution - extract information and then calculate new column:**
We can get to desired level of information with

```
map(x2$data, ~ .x$data) 

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#    cost type 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1    21 a    
# 2    30 b    
# 3    44 c    
# 4   100 d    
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#    cost type 
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1    21 a    
# 2    30 b    
# 3    44 c    
# 4   100 d    
#
# ...
```

As this is a nested list structure a second `map` is needed to calculate the new column. Here the `mutate`-function is applied to each of the nested data entries with the additional specification to create a new column inc.

```
map(x2$data, ~ map(.x$data, mutate, inc = cost + 15)) 

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    cost type    inc
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1    21 a        36
# 2    30 b        45
# 3    44 c        59
# 4   100 d       115
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    cost type    inc
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1    21 a        36
# 2    30 b        45
# 3    44 c        59
# 4   100 d       115
#
# ...
```

The same result would be obtained with an extra function `test` which takes a `data.frame` as input parameter and calculates the new column:

```
test <- function(df){
    mutate(df, increa = cost + 15)
}

map(x2$data, ~ map(.x$data, test))
```

**Second solution - Manipulate in place**
If you however want to keep this nested structure, then we use `mutate` on the first `data`-column with `map` and again `mutate` and `map`:

```
x2_new <- x2 %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, function(df1) mutate(df1, data = map(data, test))))
```

To verify that this worked we again extract the needed information as above:

```
map(x2_new$data, ~ .x$data) 


# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    cost type  increa
#   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1    21 a         36
# 2    30 b         45
# 3    44 c         59
# 4   100 d        115
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    cost type  increa
#   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1    21 a         36
# 2    30 b         45
# 3    44 c         59
# 4   100 d        115
#
# ...
```

**Third solution - breaks structure but keep information**
This is my favourite solution as it turns the data into a tidy format and keeps all information:

```
x2 %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  mutate(inc = cost + 15)

# A tibble: 16 x 5
#    scene client   cost type    inc
#    <int> <fct>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#  1     1 factory    21 a        36
#  2     1 factory    30 b        45
#  3     1 factory    44 c        59
#  4     1 factory   100 d       115
#  5     2 factory    21 a        36
#  6     2 factory    30 b        45
#  7     2 factory    44 c        59
#  8     2 factory   100 d       115
#  9     3 factory    21 a        36
# 10     3 factory    30 b        45
# 11     3 factory    44 c        59
# 12     3 factory   100 d       115
# 13     4 factory    21 a        36
# 14     4 factory    30 b        45
# 15     4 factory    44 c        59
# 16     4 factory   100 d       115
```

**Data**

```
generic_data <- structure(
  list(client = structure(1L, .Label = "factory", class = "factor"), 
       data = list(structure(list(cost = c(21, 30, 44, 100), 
                                  type = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), 
                             row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                             class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))), 
  row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

x2 <- structure(
  list(scene = 1:4, 
       data = list(generic_data, generic_data, generic_data, generic_data)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you're looking for `map_depth`

From the documentation https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map_if.html:

map_depth(x, 2, fun) is equivalent to x <- map(x, ~ map(., fun))

which looks like the answer/solution you settled on.